# Do I Need Ruby and Chef On My Vagrant Box

Tags: vagrant

I am using the trusty64 vagrant box and I provision it using puppet.

I just noticed today that ruby and chef are installed and I don't use either of them for my VM work.

Do I need them there for Vagrant to do its magic?

Can I remove them after my VM is provisioned or will `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up` stop working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so to the question

> Do I Need Ruby and Chef On My Vagrant Box

Its mainly up to you.

no, more seriously:

- Ruby comes install with Linux distro, generally some older version but its a fact that it is delivered (as python, perl ...) so you should leave it. It is not doing any harm and some other tools (including chef and puppet) relies on Ruby to be installed so if you provision with puppet you must leave ruby

Vagrant does not rely on ruby to be installed on the guest to do its magic, its mainly issuing ssh script command to do the update on network/hostname ...

- [trustry64 box](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/) is an official box from hashicorp (the company behind vagrant) and vagrant does support out of the box chef and puppet provisioning those tools are installed. Again they don't make any harm even if you're not using it.

The thing is that your box will have ruby and chef installed and whenever you boot a new VM from this box, it will contain ruby and chef, I think you will spend more time cleaning the booted VM at the end of the day, specially if you have to destroy/rebuild the VM.

If you want a minimalist box that contains only the thing you need, you can look at [packer](https://www.packer.io/) - packer is a tool to automate the creation of vagrant box, so you can really control what is install from the iso file of the OS to the libraries and 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant does rely on ruby installed in the box if you are using chef or puppet provisioner. chef/puppet runs happen inside the guest box which vagrant orchestrates using ssh.

You can remove chef when you will use chef provisioner,vagrant will download and install it again but you would need ruby for puppet.
See puppet install dependency [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/install_linux.html)